# Could we save and load the ASP.NET InProc session (hence releasing the lock) around long running external calls

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET when you have 2 AJAX requests on the same web page calling 2 controller actions, if they use the session then one will lock out the other

You can get readonly access to the session which can help, but not if you want to write to the session

You can override the session class, e.g.
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/single-asp-net-client-makes-concurrent-requests-writeable-session-variables/, but this doesn't really help for the same reason

In my case the controller action calls a long running external server call. While this is happening ideally the session would be released and saved back to memory, and then when the call is finished the session would be read back in, possibly being blocked if another call is still proceeding

NB Whether or not the external server call is called in an async manner makes no difference unfortunately

Is there any way of doing this? Possibly by overriding some internal classes?

Comment: How long is the "long running" external call in your case?

Comment: You could use an initial `IHttpHandler` that only uses `IReadOnlySessionState`, then after you finish getting the external response (and need write-access to Session) use `Server.Execute` or `Transfer` to load a different `IHttpHandler` that uses `IRequireSessionState`? This would depend on the HTTP Context (request/response) lifecycle being restarted though...

Comment: One extreme call is 30 seconds, the norm is around 3 seconds.